# Is possible to use Google Closure source code Firebase instead of compiled code?

Tags: firebase, google-closure

And the same for https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login. Since I am using full Closure Tools stack, I would rather to compile it with my project than linking compiled version.

Comment: This doesn't look hard with the Firebase base library: it's apparently run through advanced optimizations, and we're already given a debug version with much of the source code (but without annotations) through bower. Unfortunately, FirebaseSimpleLogin isn't AO-compatible, which would limit our projects to simple optimizations.

Comment: But I need AO and I need Firebase on node.js server. Any advice?